# How do I edit the WHERE clause of my VBA SQL-statement so I returns the records from more than 1 field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this basic VBA SQL-statement. I searches an external database and returns all the records where the field `[LabNumberPrimary]` = `[labnummer]` in the external database.

My VBA code repeats itself with some minor adjustments. How do I combine the 2 statements so my VBA code gets smaller and more user friendly?

1st statement:

```
cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam FROM taken t, monsters m, opdrachten o WHERE o.labnummer = " & [LabNumberPrimary] & " AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller"
```

2nd statement:

```
cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam FROM taken t, monsters m, opdrachten o WHERE o.labnummer = " & [LabNumber_4_CT] & " AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller"
```

How do I combine those 2 statements? I tried:

```
cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam FROM taken t, monsters m, opdrachten o WHERE o.labnummer = " & [LabNumberPrimary] & " AND o.labnummer = " & [LabNumber_4_CT] & " AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller"
```

But does not seem to work.

`LabNumberPrimary` and `LabNumber_4_CT` are column names in my query `qry_Administration`

EDIT:
After some research I think I know why there are  no records returning.

This piece of code:

```
AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller"
```

The 'teller' is different for both numbers. So I think the solution should be something like this: I think you guys know where I am going:

```
cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam" & _
" FROM taken t, monsters m, opdrachten o" & _
" WHERE (o.labnummer = " & [LabNumberPrimary] & _
" AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller" & _
" AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller")

" AND WHERE (o.labnummer = " & [LabNumber_4_CT] & _
" AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller" & _
" AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller")
```

Is it even possible to combine such a statement?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesnt work? Is there always 2

Comment: After some testing I think I can answer your question. No there are not always 2. So on my combined statement: I can confirm that, if the both fields are not null, then I do not get an error in Access no records are returned. If field LabNumber_4_CT is null then I get error message: [Miscrosoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was more difficult then expected. But I managed to get it working by reverse engineering. I copied the sql-statement in Query-editor, added my 3 fields but then as numbers. Then I went back to SQL-view and copied that code to my VBA code. I replaced the numbers with field names `LabNumberPrimary` `LabNumber_4_CT`.
I also had to add the Nz( function for the null values

```
LabNumberPrimary = Nz([LabNumberPrimary])
LabNumber_3_ASB = Nz([LabNumber_3_ASB])
LabNumber_4_CT = Nz([LabNumber_4_CT])

cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam FROM taken AS t, monsters AS m, opdrachten AS o WHERE (((o.labnummer)='" & LabNumberPrimary & "' Or (o.labnummer)='" & LabNumber_3_ASB & "' Or (o.labnummer)='" & LabNumber_4_CT & "') AND ((m.opdrachtteller)=[o].[opdrachtteller]) AND ((t.monsterteller)=[m].[monsterteller]))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT t.rapportnaam, t.norm, t.analysenaam" & _
" FROM taken t, monsters m, opdrachten o" & _
" WHERE o.labnummer = " & [LabNumberPrimary] & _
" OR o.labnummer = " & [LabNumber_4_CT] & _
" AND m.opdrachtteller = o.opdrachtteller" & _
" AND t.monsterteller = m.monsterteller"
```

Comment: Hi Toni, I tried your solution. I get error: [Miscrosoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Query timeout expired. I think this has to do with the amount of data with the OR statement. This should not be the case. I can confirm that both statements work, seperately, So the SQL-server returns to much records with this OR clause. It seems like i can not handle that double criteria in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If I change your solution from OR to AND, then I get the same results as my own combined sql